# Update only 50 records per date mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table for coupons in there I got lots of data's inserted already. If one user subscribes that table will be updated and assign that coupon to the user.

```
ID       coupon       user           created      Instance
1         xxxx     abc@gmail.com    2016-06-15       1
2         xxxx     def@gmail.com    2016-06-15       1
3         xxxx     ghi@gmail.com    2016-06-15       1
4         xxxx     ijk@gmail.com    2016-06-15       1
5         xxxx                      0000-00-00       0
6         xxxx                      0000-00-00       0
7         xxxx                      0000-00-00       0
```

If the user subscribes user mail and date will be created and the instance is changed to 1. I want to update only 50 users per day how can I check with query this condition?

Comment: Is 'coupon' a uniq field or is it possible that the same coupon id twice ?

Comment: in coupon field is some random letters so id will not repeat to same coupon

Comment: sorry, and how do you identify which coupon you want to update ( email or coupon or id ) ?

Comment: if the email is empty and instance is 0 and i assign to that new user email. If email is already exists that row only i update existing user row using usermail and id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a query like this. 
After execution you can test with **mysqli_affected_rows** how many rows are changed.

```
UPDATE yourTable
  SET `Instance` = 1
  , `USER` = 'theEmail'
  , `created` = now()
WHERE
  id = (SELECT `id` FROM yourTable WHERE `Instance` = 0 AND `USER` IS NULL LIMIT 1)
AND
 50 > (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourTable WHERE `created` = NOW());
```

Comment: Actually it is working awesome, but i got one more doubt. I want to redirect two pages using this condition if  within fifty means redirect to thank you page else sorry page how to i check that?

Comment: after the UPDATE query use mysqli_affected_rows to find out how many records are changed. if 1 so it updated a row, if 0 - now update -> sorry page

Comment: It's Running... Thank you for your Time @Bernd Buffen